# Apache crashing when I add Far-Future Expires clause from Rails Guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

In an attempt to serve my precompiled assets with Apache, per [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) Rails Guide I try to change this:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/release_checklist/public"
  <Directory "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/release_checklist/public">
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
  ProxyPreserveHost On  
</VirtualHost>
```

To this:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/release_checklist/public"
  <Directory "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/release_checklist/public">
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    # RFC says only cache for 1 year
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

in my `httpd.conf` file. However, the Apache server won't start when the second option has been added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error does it give you? Are you sure you have mod_expires compiled into apache and that the module is loaded?

Comment: The only way I can see any errors is in the Windows Event Log; the command line and gui launchers fail silently. The event log reports the following error:

    The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> Syntax error on line 520 of C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:

    Invalid command 'ExpiresActive', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: The mod_expires module was indeed commented out. Result of being an Apache noob and the Rails Guides assuming I would know to do this -.-The server is now running correctly, thanks for your help! If you post your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What error does it give you? Are you sure you have mod_expires compiled into apache and that the module is loaded?

> Invalid command 'ExpiresActive', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Yeah, that's usually the error you get if you use a directive that's mapped to a module that isn't loaded (or just a mispelled directive, which appears the same to apache). You'll need to check httpd.conf and make sure the `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so` line is not commented out, of if it's missing, to add it. Depending on your apache's version, the line can be slightly different.