# .htaccess 500 Internal Server Error - FilesMatch could not be working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've downloaded a website project with the intention of replicating the website locally and work with it locally until I finished the project and then send it back to the hosting service.

I downloaded the website folder and added it to www folder in Wamp.
Wamp is working fine, (tested index sample). I exported the databases and imported them to phpMyAdmin locally.  Then I created user/password to access the databases from the website.  I assigned all the privileges to that user.

My Website structure is www/html/system.  I have an .htaccess with redirects to the system folder. The redirect works fine.  In the system folder I have another .htaccess file shown below.

In the .htaccess file of my website I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php  

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-5 .php
#</IfModule>

#Error Document
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.example.com/error400.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/error403.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error404.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/error500.html

#FileETag none

#expires after one month

<FilesMatch "^(_images/new_logo.png|_images/default-player.png|_images/default-team.png|storage/events/1/event01.jpg|_images/help.png|_images/bigpicture_regular.png|_images/facebook.png|_images/twitter.png|_images/default_member_pic.gif|_images/feedback.png|storage/events/2/event01.jpg|_images/dot.png|_buttons/home.png|_buttons/media_forward.png|_buttons/print.png|_jquery/jquery-ui.js|_jquery/jScrollbar.jquery.css|_jquery/jquery.js|_jquery/jScrollbar.jquery.js|_jquery/jquery-mousewheel.js|_fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js|_fancybox/ajax.txt|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox-y.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox-x.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_right.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_over.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_main.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_left.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_w.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_sw.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_se.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_s.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_ne.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_e.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_nav_right.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_nav_left.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_loading.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_close.png|_fancybox/fancybox/blank.gif|_images/topMenuImages.png|_images/bg_slider4.png|_images/bg_jScrollbar_draggable.jpg|_images/bg_draggable5.png|_images/bg_draggable4.png|_images/header_logo.png|_images/home_logo.png|storage/events/2/event01.jpg)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>

# Good for one week

ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M604800
ExpiresByType text/css M604800
ExpiresByType text/html M604800
```

What outputs in the web browser is:  Internal Server Error 500 `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request....`. I've commented the block that edits the file extensions (.php and .html).  I also took out the whole FileMatch section, but it stills keep appearing the Internal Server Error.

I appreciate any comment or feedback in this issue. Thank you very much for your time,  I appreciate it.

Regards,

NMV

Comment: What appears in the Apache error_log?

Comment: btw, you don't need to use `RewriteEngine on` twice in one file. Just define it at the top

Comment: Thank you Sergio.  I'm maintaining the code, I'll apply your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @JRD, I forgot that essential stuff for debugging.  In the Apache Error Log appears ...C:/wamp/www/html/system/.htaccess: Invalid command 'ExpiresActive', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.  It also appears the same for Expirestype.  If I comment those in the .htaccess file then the website appears, but without some styling.

Comment: Can you verify you have the Module mod_expires enabled? Your apache config should have something similar to `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so`

Comment: I took @Jon Lin suggestion and it worked.  If I place in the file his suggestions and then I turn expires_module modules/mod_expires.so on, then Internal Server Error appears again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invalid command 'ExpiresActive', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. It also appears the same for Expirestype.

This error is caused by the mod_expires module not loading.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618055/851273

So you can either wrap the offending line with a check, load the mod_expires module by making sure it's uncommented in the httpd.conf file (or use a2enmod), or remove those lines.

You can wrap this around it to just make the error go away:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
      #expires after one month

    <FilesMatch "^(_images/new_logo.png|_images/default-player.png|_images/default-team.png|storage/events/1/event01.jpg|_images/help.png|_images/bigpicture_regular.png|_images/facebook.png|_images/twitter.png|_images/default_member_pic.gif|_images/feedback.png|storage/events/2/event01.jpg|_images/dot.png|_buttons/home.png|_buttons/media_forward.png|_buttons/print.png|_jquery/jquery-ui.js|_jquery/jScrollbar.jquery.css|_jquery/jquery.js|_jquery/jScrollbar.jquery.js|_jquery/jquery-mousewheel.js|_fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js|_fancybox/ajax.txt|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css|_fancybox/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox-y.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancybox-x.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_right.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_over.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_main.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_title_left.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_w.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_sw.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_se.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_s.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_ne.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_shadow_e.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_nav_right.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_nav_left.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_loading.png|_fancybox/fancybox/fancy_close.png|_fancybox/fancybox/blank.gif|_images/topMenuImages.png|_images/bg_slider4.png|_images/bg_jScrollbar_draggable.jpg|_images/bg_draggable5.png|_images/bg_draggable4.png|_images/header_logo.png|_images/home_logo.png|storage/events/2/event01.jpg)$">
      ExpiresActive on 
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Good for one week

    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M604800
    ExpiresByType text/css M604800
    ExpiresByType text/html M604800  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you Jon Lin.  Is really helpful your advice and I appreciate it you taking your time to help me solve this.  I need to ask, what is the best practice to place the wrap of the Expires... in the top of the .htaccess file or in the bottom of it?

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you.